# work on a remote server

Tags: server, ssh

I have a multicore experiment to do on a remote university ubuntu server. the way my project is set up at the moment is rather heavy and not optimal.

I write code on my laptop -> **scp** the file from my local machine to the server-> execute and redirect the results to a file -> scp the file back to my local machine -> then explore the results. I can't do execution on my laptop because it's a big multicore experiment so to even optimize my code correct it and finesse it, I have been going back and forth with the file which is time and effort consuming.

the server belongs to the uni and I am NOT root and so I can't do any of the **mount** stuff.

do you have any suggestions on how I can work directly on the server to avoid all this hustle.

Comment: You might try and mount the remote filesystem locally using `sshfs`. See e.g. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSHFS and https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh

Comment: @ByteCommander don't I need to be root in both machines to do that?

Comment: You only need to install the `sshfs` package on your local machine (assuming Ubuntu laptop, but there seems to be a Windows client too - see the DigitalOcean link above). There is no installation or root access required on the remote server. It needs to have the SFTP subsystem of ssh enabled though.

Comment: @ByteCommander I have just installed sshfs on my mac and I am attempting the mount

Answer (score 0):

I mounted the remote directory to my own local machine following this :
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-directories-over-ssh/

I am working on the remote files as if I am working on my own local machine